# Symfony : form with GET method, messy URL

Tags: php, forms, symfony, get

I use a search form in Symfony 4.2.5, with `GET` method.
But the URL is not very... sexy.
I want to get a clean URL.

I have already disabled CSRF protection, and removed the submit from the FormBuilder ( otherwise, the submit button was ALSO on the URL).

The form :

```
public function searchForm()
{
    //Form search creation
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(null,  array('csrf_protection' => false))
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('page'))
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->add('object', TextType::class)
            ->getForm();

    return $this->render('page.html.twig', ['searchForm' => $searchForm->createView()]);
}
```

The view :

```
<form class="search">
    {{ form_start(searchForm) }}
    {{ form_row(searchForm.object, {'attr' : {'placeholder': "Search..."}}) }}
    <button id="searchSubmit" class="btn btn-success">Search </button>
    {{ form_end(searchForm) }}
</form>
```

With this code, I get `localhost/page?form[object]=SearchTerm`

I know, it is a detail, but I want to get an URL like `localhost/page?object=SearchTerm`.

Comment: Use method POST instead of GET.

Comment: I need method GET instead of POST.

Comment: either you can use post method or data submit using ajax.

Comment: you have to create a named form builder (where you can get rid of the "form"), that should be enough.